# Can I ask memory lickage from c++ code?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Edge;

class Node
{

    public :

    int cost;

    vector<Edge* > edges;

    Edge* from;

    string name;

    bool onq;

    Node()
    {
        cost = 100;
        from = NULL;
        onq = false;
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);
        delete from;
    }


    void clear()
    {
        cost = 0;
        vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);
        from = NULL;
    }
};

class Edge
{
    public:

    Node* destination;

    int capacity;

    int cost;

    Edge* dual;

    Edge()
    {
    }

    ~Edge()
    {
        vector<Edge*>().swap(destination->edges);

        delete destination;

        delete dual;

        destination =  NULL;
        dual = NULL;
    }

    Edge(Node* n, int c, int s)
    {
        capacity = c;

        cost = s;

        destination = n;

        dual = NULL;
    }

};

int MCMF(Node* src, Node* snk, vector<Node*> &nodes)
{
    int result = 0;

    list<Node* > queue;

while(true)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodes.size() ; ++i)
    {
        nodes.at(i)->cost = 100;
        nodes.at(i)->from = NULL;
    }

    src->cost = 0;

    queue.clear();
    queue.push_back(src);

    src->onq = true;

    int count = 0;

    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        Node* node = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        node->onq = false;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < node->edges.size() ; ++i)
        {
            Edge* edge = node->edges[i];

            if(edge->capacity > 0 && node->cost + edge->cost < edge->destination->cost)
            {
                edge->destination->cost = node->cost + edge->cost;

                edge->destination->from = edge;

                if(!edge->destination->onq)
                {
                    edge->destination->onq = true;
                    queue.push_back(edge->destination);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(snk->from == NULL)
        break;

    int min = 0x7FFFFFFF;

    for(Node* node = snk ; node->from != NULL ; )
    {
        Edge* edge = node->from;

        if(edge->capacity < min)
            min = edge->capacity;

        node = edge->dual->destination;
    }

    for(Node* node = snk ; node->from != NULL ;)
    {
        Edge* edge = node->from;

        edge->capacity -= min;

        edge->dual->capacity += min;

        node = edge->dual->destination;
    }
    result += snk->cost;


    for(list<Node*>::iterator iter = queue.begin() ; iter != queue.end() ; ++iter)
        delete (*iter);

    queue.clear();

}

return result;

}

void link(Node *node1, Node *node2, int capacity, int cost)
{
    Edge* e1 = new Edge(node2, capacity, cost);
    Edge* e2 = new Edge(node1, 0, -cost);

    e1->dual = e2;
    e2->dual = e1;

    node1->edges.push_back(e1);
    node2->edges.push_back(e2);

}

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    vector<Node* > nodes;

    while(cin >> n >> m)
    {
        if(n == 0 && m == 0)
            break;

        nodes.clear();

        Node* source = new Node();
        nodes.push_back(source);

        Node* sink = new Node();
        nodes.push_back(sink);

        vector<vector<Node* > > position(n);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
        {
            int p;

            cin >> p;

            position[i] = vector<Node*>(p);

            for(int j = 0 ; j < p ; ++j)
            {
                Node* node = new Node;

                position[i][j] = node;


            nodes.push_back(node);

            link(node, sink, 1, 0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i)
    {
        Node* student = new Node();

        nodes.push_back(student);

        link(source, student, 1, 0);

        int year, cost;

        cin >> year;
        cost = 13 - year*4;

        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; ++j)
        {
            int pre;
            cin >> pre;

            for(int k = 0 ; k < position[pre].size() ; ++k)
            {
                link(student, position[pre][k], 1, cost+j);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << 13*m-MCMF(source, sink, nodes) << endl;

    delete source;
    delete sink;

    for(vector<vector<Node*> >::iterator iter1 = position.begin() ; iter1 != position.end() ; ++ iter1)
        for(vector<Node*>::iterator iter2 = (*iter1).begin(); iter2 != (*iter1).end() ; ++iter2)
            delete (*iter2);

    vector<vector<Node *> >().swap(position);

    vector<Node*>().swap(nodes);
    }
}
```

this is my whole code

this code created for MCMF graph algorithm

I submit this code to algorithm site but fail because memory excess

this code has more than 128mb....

i think that not free memory allocated in link function

I try catch memory leak in visual studio then many log appeared but I can't think solution

Im sorry to code's length

can I find solution this allocation

thank you

Comment: Probably off topic, but... Turn up/pay attention to the compiler warnings. Compiler should tell you that there is no destructor implemented for `Edge` at the time of the `Node` destructor. Forward define makes `Edge` known, but you do a lot of work in the `Edge` destructor and I don't know it it's going to be called correctly because it has yet to be defined. You can solve this by moving `Node::~Node` out of the `Node` class and below `Edge`.

Comment: OK. Probably not off topic. Built the program to get the compiler warning and found `Edge`'s destructor was compiled out. And the warning messages say this will happen. GCC: "neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined" VS2010: warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'Edge'; no destructor called.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for comment :D

Comment: Use a smart pointers to do the memory management for you.http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: `shared_ptr` is great, but it's dangerous with graphs. It's really easy to make a cycle and then what? Reference count never hits 0, Node never gets deleted. Memory leak. A Node pool made from a `vector<unique_ptr<Node>>` gives you one stop shopping for all your node and memory management needs. All you have to do is delete the vector and all the nodes are gone. There are better ways to memory manage your nodes, but this is at least easy, easy to prove, and works well enough.

Comment: Thank you for gain new knowledge have a good day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are next to impossible to answer because no one really knows what is going on in the online judge, but here's a hum-dinger of a memory leak for you to fix:

Class `Node`s destructor,

```
~Node()
{
    vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);
    delete from;
}
```

`delete`s an `Edge` before `Edge`'s destructor has been defined. This is uncool, because the program can't call the `Edge` destructor to free whatever resources `Edge` owns. And it looks like `~Edge` is far from trivial:

```
~Edge()
{
    vector<Edge*>().swap(destination->edges);

    delete destination;

    delete dual;

    destination =  NULL;
    dual = NULL;
}
```

None of that code will ever run. By the way, setting `destination` and `dual` to NULL is wasted effort. This `Edge` is gone in another few clock cycles, so no one will ever care.

Also, `vector<Edge*>().swap(destination->edges);` almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to do. It's not freeing any of those `Edge`s. It's just moving the pointers to a temporary that's about to go out of scope and lose those edge pointers forever.

Solution:

Move `~Node` to after the definition of `~Edge`

```
class Node
{
    ...
    ~Node(); // declare only
    ...
};

class Edge
{
    ...
};

Node::~Node()
{
    vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);
    delete from;
}
```

And as above this `vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);` probably isn't doing anything of use to you. I suspect you are after something more like this:

```
Node::~Node()
{
    for (Edge * edge: edges)
    {
        delete edge;
    }
    delete from;
}
```

And I recommend thinking really hard about what you are doing with `from`.

On second thought, rethink how you are doing this. Deleting the `Edge::destination` is almost certainly a bad idea because, unless this is a one directional tree, any given `Node` could be the destination of another `Edge`. `delete`ing anything more than once is not a good idea. Having the same `Node` represented by more than one object is also a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for comment :D I will worried about them

Answer (score 0):

Clearing a vector does not free the memory from the objects that the vector elements are pointing to. You need to clear the memory for all the Edge* in the vector before clearing the vector itself. Do this in any other part of your code that has a vector of pointers. Add the same thing to the ~Node() as well.

```
void clear()
    {
        cost = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++){
            edges[i]->~Edge();
        }
        vector<Edge *>().swap(edges);
        from = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for comment :D